# react-native not working on physical device

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native so please help me start with that .I just create my first react-native project by using this command

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

I already install android studio and add path of sdk in environment. Also done with developer option in my android. When I run that command

```
npx react-native run-android
```

it gives me a lot of errors like that

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'E:\react_native\AwesomeProject\android\local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Answer (score 2):

- Go to the android/ directory of your react-native project
- Create a file called local.properties with this line:

> sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk

Where USERNAME is your macOS username

More Info found [here](https://medium.com/codespace69/react-native-run-react-native-got-error-sdk-location-not-found-5ff2116269ec)